# How to count number of lines in a string using R?

Tags: r, string

My intention is to get the number of lines/rows in a given text. In the text, semicolon denotes the end of each line. For instance, consider the following text.

```
txt <- "This is text mining exercise; How to count the number of lines in a string; A statement between two semicolons is considered as one line; Thank you"
length(txt)
[1] 1
```

As shown above, length(txt) outputs 1, which is not what I want. Can someone help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to count based on the `;`, then one option is `str_count` to count the number of occurrence of `;` and add 1 to it

```
library(stringr)
str_count(txt, ";") + 1
#[1] 4
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
nchar(gsub("[^;]+", "", txt)) + 1
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your swift reply!